# How to identify that the input String has a is variable or not

Tags: c

One of my tasks is to identify the input string has a variable or not.

For example: User might enter a string `#define int a,ab;` and in this string i want to identify which is one is variable
example 2 : User might also enter '#anything float a,b,c;' and now here i again want to identify that what variable did user entered

How to identify this, in C language?

Comment: Parse the input?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: It is clear that you don't have enough programming pratice to think of a logic to determine how you can decide if expression you are trying to parse is declaring a variable. You can start with a logic like this: If expression on hand starts with #define following with int keyword and a name after it than it is a variable decleration.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create a new variable based on an input string?
So the types to search a string for would include ("char","int","short","long","float","double"). This is a nice basic set of types to check a string for.

Now iterate through the input string and check if any word from the set is contained in the string. To do this I would suggest `strcmp(str1,str2)`

If any of the types is found in the input, you can assume whatever comes after it is the identifier.

Read about string iteration and string comparison and apply these methods and you should have this program finished in no time.